# Overriding a custom attribute in a flavor by referring to another style

Tags: android, attributes, resources

I have two cardStyle attributes defined in the same file in my module as follows:

--> module/src/main/res/values/styles.xml

```
<declare-styleable name="customAttr">
    <attr name="cardStyle" format="reference" />
    <attr name="settingsCardStyle" format="reference" />
</declare-styleable>
<style name="CardStyle" parent="CardView">
    <item name="cardCornerRadius">0dp</item>
    <item name="cardElevation">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginEnd">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginStart">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginTop">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">0dp</item>
</style>
<style name="SettingsCardStyle" parent="CardView">
    <item name="android:layout_marginEnd">16dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginStart">16dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginTop">16dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">59dp</item>
</style>
```

After that I want to override the settingsCardStyle referring to cardStyle in my flavour which is located in my app component:

--> app/src/flavor/res/values/styles.xml

```
<style name="CardStyle" parent="CardView">
    <item name="cardCornerRadius">8dp</item>
    <item name="cardElevation">6dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginEnd">16dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginStart">16dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginTop">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">10dp</item>
</style>
<style name="SettingsCardStyle">
    <item name="cardStyle">@style/CardStyle</item>
    //using the following, the style works but it is redundant.
    <!--<item name="cardCornerRadius">8dp</item>-->
    <!--<item name="cardElevation">6dp</item>-->
    <!--<item name="android:layout_marginEnd">16dp</item>-->
    <!--<item name="android:layout_marginStart">16dp</item>-->
    <!--<item name="android:layout_marginTop">10dp</item>-->
    <!--<item name="android:layout_marginBottom">10dp</item>-->
</style>
```

I must mention that I have a CommonTheme as below:

--> app/src/main/res/values/styles.xml

```
<style name="CommonTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/open_sans</item>
    <item name="fontFamily">@font/open_sans</item>
    <item name="cardStyle">@style/CardStyle</item>
    <item name="settingsCardStyle">@style/SettingsCardStyle</item>
</style>
```

But this is not working. The main app recognizes the style in the module but the flavored app does not...

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem!
The solution is to use inheritance rather referring to another style.

```
<style name="CardStyle" parent="CardView">
    <item name="cardCornerRadius">8dp</item>
    <item name="cardElevation">6dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginEnd">16dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginStart">16dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginTop">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">10dp</item>
</style>

<style name="SettingsCardStyle" parent="CardStyle">
```

Comment: Ok, so `<style name="SettingsCardStyle" parent="CardStyle">` rathen than `<style name="SettingsCardStyle" parent="CardView">`. Accept your own answer to close it please ;)

Answer (score 1):

So you want to override a style from a flavor:

Resource qualifiers allows that in `app/src/flavor1/res` etc.

*OLD ANSWER (regarding modules, not flavors)*

To share a style between modules, I'm using an intermediate one:

common:

```
<style name="_CardStyle" parent="CardView"></style>
```

module1 (depends on common):

```
<style name="CardStyle" parent="_CardStyle"></style>
```

module2 (depends on common):

```
<style name="CardStyle" parent="_CardStyle"></style>
```

You can now use `CardStyle` in your modules.

Comment: I don't want to share the CardStyle between modules rather I want to override it in my flavor. And I want to use my default card style for my settingsCardstyle. If I rewrite everything in my settingsCardStyle it works but I wanna reuse my CardStyle.

Comment: My bad indeed. Then resource qualifiers should do the trick. Edited.

Comment: I already have the flavoured resources but my mistake was that I was trying to refer to another style in my customised style while I should have used inheritance.